# std::string allocation policy

Tags: c++, memory, alignment, allocator, stdstring

I am a bit confused with some of the basic string implementation. I have been going through the source to understand the inner working and learn new things. I can't entirely grasp how the memory is managed.

Just some tidbits from the basic string implementation

- The raw allocator is for char type

  ```
  typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<char>::other _Raw_bytes_alloc;
  ```
- ...then when allocating Rep is placed within the allocated buffer `__size` is calculated to also fit the characters

  ```
  size_type __size = (__capacity + 1) * sizeof(_CharT) + sizeof(_Rep);
  void* __place = _Raw_bytes_alloc(__alloc).allocate(__size);
  _Rep *__p = new (__place) _Rep;
  ```
- This is how the character data is fetched from the _Rep buffer

  ```
  _CharT* _M_refdata() throw()
  {
      return reinterpret_cast<_CharT*>(this + 1);
  }
  ```
- Setting up the character - for one type of way

  ```
  _M_assign(__p->_M_refdata(), __n, __c);
  ```

What is bothering me is that the raw allocator is type char, but the allocated memory may hold a _Rep object, plus the character data (which does not have to be type char)

Also, why (or rather how) does the call to `_M_refdata` know where the start (or end) of the character data is within the buffer (ie `this+1`)

Edit: does `this+1` just push the internal pointer to the next position after the `_Rep` object?

I have a basic understanding of memory alignment and casting, but this seems to go beyond anything I have read up on.

Can anybody help, or point me to more informative reading material?

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the placement new. The line

```
_Rep *__p = new (__place) _Rep;
```

initializes a new `_Rep`-object at `__place`. The space for this has already been allocated before (meaning a placement-new doesn't allocate by itself, it's actually only a constructor call).

Pointer arithmetics in C and C++ tells you, that `this + 1` is a pointer that points `sizeof(*this)` bytes right of `this`. Since there have been allocated `(__capacity + 1) * sizeof(_CharT) + sizeof(_Rep)` bytes before, the space after the `_Rep` object is used for the character data. The layout is thus like this:

```
| _Rep |  (__capacity + 1) * _CharT  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocators, like C's `malloc`, return pointers to bytes, not objects. So, the return type is either `char *` or `void *`.

Somewhere in the C and C++ standards, there is a clause that explicitly allows reinterpret casting between `char` and any other object type. This is because C often needs to treat objects as byte arrays (as when writing to disk or a network socket) and it needs to treat byte arrays as objects (like when allocating a range of memory or reading from disk).

To protect against aliasing and optimization problems, you're *not* allowed to cast the same `char *` to different types of objects and once you've casted a `char *` to an object type, you are not allowed to modify the object's value by writing to the bytes.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `char`. You can `reinterpret_cast` all simple pointer types into each other.

Comment: @filmor: not true. That violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @filmor: The language will *let* you do it, but it does not promise to compile it to do what you think it should do. For example, after casting a `char*` to `double` it might load the double into a register. Then you write something to the `char *`. It *will not* change the value of the `double`.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me :). The rule of thumb "it compiles" just doesn't work here ;)

Comment: ok thanks (filmor and zan). the default string allocator (eg std::allocator<wchar_t> , std::allocator<char> ,...) is the argument to the _Raw_bytes_alloc which is std::allocator<char>. is this correct? then why is this?

Comment: nevermind-reread the 1st paragraph, which is prob the reason this is acceptable