# Guaranteed allocation size in std::string initialization.\

Tags: c++, c++17

There are a variety of questions around this topic already on this site:

- [Guarantees on C++ std::string heap memory allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127851/guarantees-on-c-stdstring-heap-memory-allocation)
- [std::string allocation policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810194/stdstring-allocation-policy)

My question is different from these in that I am interested in how std::string determines its original capacity and how I can rightsize a string assuming that I know how many bytes exactly I will need. Calling `reserve(n)` can result in the string allocating more memory and I need it to be 24 bytes (right above the sso threshold, can't fit under). Overallocation would be quite dramatic as I potentially hold millions of these in memory, so if it, e.g., aligns at 32 bytes the 33% overhead really hurts. Naturally I would also like to avoid the potential reallocation from `shrink_to_fit`.

My understanding is that you can get an exact allocation size by initializing as `std::string(rightsized_constant, size)` via the `const char*, size_t` ctor, but of course nothing guarantees this.

Is there a reasonably clean way to get this using `std::string`?

Comment: for fixed size 24 I would consider a `std::array<char>`, you have complete control over its size

Comment: That's generally sound advice, but I explicitly asked about std::string, since the bytes are appended by an API I don't want to change that it takes `std::string*`

Comment: If you have stringent application-specific requirements (such as exactly 24 bytes) then you probably should roll you down data structure. Needing to use an `std::string*` (not a reference?) doesn't change that; if size is critical, copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I used after some thinking, discussion with a coworker and brief experiments with clang++/g++ on Linux.

```
template<typename T>
class Reader {
  void operator()(T key, std::string* append_to);
};
...
Reader a;
Reader b;
std::string s;
std::vector<KeyType> keys = ...;
std::vector<std::string> out;
out.reserve(keys.size());
for (const auto& key : keys) {
  a(key, &s);
  b(key, &s);
  out.emplace_back(s); // relies on assumption that copy will rightsize
  s.clear(); // relies on the implicit guarantee that this doesn't release memory
} // s rightsized after first iteration
```

Still curious if anything actually gives a guarantee.

Comment: what is `v`, `a` and `b` ? It is not clear what this code does

Comment: clarified a bit, hope it is better now. Was in a slight rush at work and couldn't copy the code which contained internal types.

Comment: it seems like the whole point of the example is `std::string s; c.emplace_back(s);` and relying on the copy constructor to not allocate more than needed. The rest is unclear

Comment: That's half the point. The other half is that s.clear() doesn't release memory, so on all but the first iteration, writing to s does not result in any allocations if the size of the values returned by the readers are constant.